# VS & VS code customize shortcuts for common actions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, shortcut, end-of-line

I'm wondering if there is a way to customize any shortcut in Visual Studio / VSCode?

E.g. I don't like using the "end" button to go to the end of the current line because I don't want to move my right hand to far away from the main A-Z keys.

Comment: Hi Erick, any update of this issue, have you checked the answer I posted, does it work for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, you can follow the steps below to change many default short-cuts of Visual STudio:

1, Click Tools -> Options of the bar on the top of the VS.

[image]

2, Select Keyboard under the Environment section.

[image]

3, Search 'Edit.LineEnd':

[image]

4, Change the setting:

[image]

After that, you will be able to go to the end of the current line with a key-combination on the left-hand side of the keyboard.

For more shortcut setting changing steps you can refer to this official document:

[Identify and customize keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

For the specific keyboard introduction, I didn't find a official document, but I think just have a look of the name and the original setting will help you make sure this setting is what you want.